# Is there a way to include a vpython window in a Tkinter frame or canvas?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, 3d, vpython

I'm trying to include an interactive **vpython** window in a **tkinter** *frame* or *canvas* in order to visualise simple shapes (representing the mechanical assembly that will be sized). I can't find a *frame* or *canvas* method to integrate a vpython window properly. Do you know if it's even possible ? If it's not doable, which programming language should I pick to realize a GUI including 3D visualisation ?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: python runs on processor, it doesn't use GPU at all so complex 3D stuff doesn't go well with it, for that some other programming language should be used, however if it is not too complex stuff You could theoretically use `ursina engine` which is a game engine that allows to do 3D stuff pretty well so could try that, as for tkinter, I imagine that would not be easy, tho You could actually provide an example of how that would look like

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don't want to use wxpython? It is not an easy task to combine two different fameworks.

Comment: thanks for your kind answers, I will restart my GUI coding with PyQt. I will be able to generate 3D shapes with the openGL module included in this library